# Remove elements in a string separated by commas in groovy

Tags: string, groovy, null, remove-if

I am building a string in this way:

```
def presentationType = "${feedDisplayType}, ${moduleType}, ${cellType}"
```

What happens is that sometimes the variables has null values, and the resulting string is showing this null values, I have to avoid show null values.

I want to know if there is some way to remove this possible null values in the string or avoid add this when they will be presented.

I know that it is possible and more easy to do with arrays, but I want to do it with strings in a more direct way.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 options:

#### 1. GString interpolation

```
def presentationType = "${feedDisplayType != null && !feedDisplayType.isEmpty() ? feedDisplayType + ', ' : ''}${moduleType != null && !moduleType.isEmpty() ? moduleType + ', ' : ''}${cellType != null && !cellType.isEmpty() ? cellType : ''}".toString()
```

#### 2. Using `StringBuilder`

```
def sb = new StringBuilder()
if (feedDisplayType != null && !feedDisplayType.isEmpty()) {
    sb.append(feedDisplayType)
    sb.append(', ')
}
if (moduleType != null && !moduleType.isEmpty()) {
    sb.append(moduleType)
    sb.append(', ')
}
if (cellType != null && !cellType.isEmpty()) {
    sb.append(cellType)
}
def presentationType = sb.toString()
```

#### 3. Joining a list with `,` as a delimiter

```
def presentationType = [feedDisplayType, moduleType, cellType].findAll { str -> str != null && !str.isEmpty() }.join(', ')
```

### Benchmark

Before going into conclusion let's benchmark all 3 methods using [GBench](https://github.com/gperfutils/gbench) tool:

```
@Grab(group='org.gperfutils', module='gbench', version='0.4.3-groovy-2.4')

def feedDisplayType = 'test'
def moduleType = null
def cellType = ''

def r = benchmark {

    'GString method' {
        def presentationType = "${feedDisplayType != null && !feedDisplayType.isEmpty() ? feedDisplayType + ', ' : ''}${moduleType != null && !moduleType.isEmpty() ? moduleType + ', ' : ''}${cellType != null && !cellType.isEmpty() ? cellType : ''}".toString()
    }
    'StringBuilder method' {
        def sb = new StringBuilder()
        if (feedDisplayType != null && !feedDisplayType.isEmpty()) {
            sb.append(feedDisplayType)
            sb.append(', ')
        }
        if (moduleType != null && !moduleType.isEmpty()) {
            sb.append(moduleType)
            sb.append(', ')
        }
        if (cellType != null && !cellType.isEmpty()) {
            sb.append(cellType)
        }
        def presentationType = sb.toString()
    }
    'Join list method' {
        def presentationType = [feedDisplayType, moduleType, cellType].findAll { str -> str != null && !str.isEmpty() }.join(', ')
    }
}
r.prettyPrint()
```

#### Output

```
Environment
===========
* Groovy: 2.4.12
* JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.171-b10, Oracle Corporation)
    * JRE: 1.8.0_171
    * Total Memory: 236 MB
    * Maximum Memory: 3497 MB
* OS: Linux (4.16.5-200.fc27.x86_64, amd64)

Options
=======
* Warm Up: Auto (- 60 sec)
* CPU Time Measurement: On

                      user  system  cpu  real

GString method         265       2  267   268
StringBuilder method    72       4   76    77
Join list method       484       3  487   495
```

### Conclusion

If you aim towards highest throughput, `StringBuilder` method is the best one (77 nanoseconds mean time).

`GString` method is a few times slower than `StringBuilder` and it is much less readable due to all condition statements inside a single GString. It is also pretty error prone - it's easy to make a mistake when interpolating String in this case.

Joining list method is the slowest one (only 2 times slower approximately than GString method), but it is the cleanest one. And it is still pretty fast - 495 nanoseconds is acceptable in most cases. Of course optimization depends on specific use case - if you have to execute this part of code million times per second, then using `StringBuilder` instead makes much more sense.

### Benchmark corner cases

To make this example complete let's also take a look at corner cases in benchmarking. We use the same code with different input.

Input:

```
def feedDisplayType = 'lorem ipsum'
def moduleType = 'dolor sit amet'
def cellType = '123456789'
```

Output:

```
                      user  system  cpu  real

GString method         387       1  388   390
StringBuilder method   170       0  170   175
Join list method       847       6  853   859
```

Input:

```
def feedDisplayType = ''
def moduleType = ''
def cellType = ''
```

Output:

```
                      user  system  cpu  real

GString method         237       5  242   242
StringBuilder method    44       0   44    44
Join list method       441       0  441   446
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** This answer has been changed as there is a requirement to not print "," for null terms.

Consider:

```
def feedDisplayType = 'abc'
def moduleType = null
def cellType = 'ijk'

def f = { s, isLast = false ->
    def token = s ?: ''
    def seperator = (!s || isLast) ? '' : ',' 
    "${token}${seperator}"
}

def presentationType = "${f feedDisplayType}${f moduleType}${f cellType,true}"
assert 'abc,ijk' == presentationType
```

Note that in function calls, parens are optional in Groovy so `${f x}` is equivalent to `${f(x)}`. `f` was originally `field` in an earlier version, but I've shortened it for brevity.

Comment: Yeah it is almost what I am looking for, but also I have to avoid the , is interesting your approach.

Comment: In that way will be something like: presentationType": ", , example" and shoul be presentationType": "example". Thanks

Comment: If avoiding the commas is a requirement, then you should update the question with that information.

Comment: I have changed the answer to address the issue on ",". The question is unclear about spaces, so I'm assuming that we don't want extra spaces.